# The starting point of next epoch for fit_generator in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, generator

In Keras documentation, `steps_per_epoch` in `fit_generator` means:

> Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch.

I am wondering if I have an infinite generator, then where do I start when I enter the next epoch? Do I pick up where I was left? Or do I start over from the first sample again?

Comment: Yes, Keras will not see any "end" in your generator, it will simply pick the `next(generator)` sample sequentially and infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the definition of your generator. Actually, if you have a generator that yields batches infinitely, then you must make sure it is defined such that after iterating over all the samples (i.e. one epoch) it goes back to the starting point (i.e. we don't generate a sample more than once in an epoch). For example, a rough sketch of such a generator would be like this:

```py
def my_gen(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
    n_samples = x_train.shape[0]
    n_steps = np.ceil(n_samples // batch_size)
    while True:
        # one epoch: goes over all the samples
        for i in range(n_steps):
            # the last batch might have less than batch_size samples
            if (i+1) * batch_size > n_samples:
                x = x_train[i * batch_size:]
                y = y_train[i * batch_size:]
            else:  
                x = x_train[i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size]
                y = y_train[i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size]
            yield x, y
```

Comment: Let's take your code as example. If n_steps is 100, batch_size is 1 and I set steps_per_epoch to be 32 in fit_generator. When it finishes the first epoch and gets to start the second, will it start from the 33rd sample or start over from the 1st?

Comment: @YixiangCai If `n_steps=100` and `batch_size=1` then the number of samples is equal to 100. Now, if you set the `steps_per_epoch=32` it means each epoch 32 batches of size 1 are generated. Therefore, after the first epoch is finished, it will start from the 33rd sample as you mentioned. However, you should set `steps_per_epoch` equal to the number of samples divided by batch size (as `n_steps` is set internally). In this way, you make sure you have used all the samples exactly one time in an epoch (of course, considering that generator is defined as above).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps!